# Getting cover photos with Google+ Search API results

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to search Google+ accounts through the Javascript API but even when supplying fields param and telling it to retrieve cover photos it still doesn't retrieve it.

[Example search API call with cover field selected](http://goo.gl/6LAK7G)

Any idea if this limitation is part of the Google+ search API? This doesn't seem to happen in the people.get calls.

Comment: Do you have an example post that you expect to see cover photos on but doesn't ave one?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am talking about the people.search API in Google+ and getting the cover image of the users profile. An example is the link I posted in the question. Any other information in specific you think would be useful?

Comment: I misunderstood what API you were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The people search returns only limited information about the person.  You need to take the ID returned from People search and call People get.

From the documentation: [People: search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search)

> items[] list The people in this page of results. Each item includes
>   the id, displayName, image, and url for the person. To retrieve
>   additional profile data, see the people.get method.

[People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)
If successful, this method returns a [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) in the response body.

```
"cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-G93N-0rUMcU/U8z2FJW_eNI/AAAAAAAAKe0/zcIwm7NmPRc/s630-fcrop64=1,003a0000ffc4ffff/LindaLawtonGoogleplusCover.png",
   "height": 528,
   "width": 940

  },
```